# Inititiate a SAML 2.0 Post to an SP for an already Authenticated User

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I need to implement SSO for a third party product our company has purchased (Service Provider). They need a SAML 2.0 token Posted to their server. We plan to implement this in an Application Page in SharePoint where we already have the user authenticated (Windows Sign-on). All I need to do is create the Token and send it along. However, I am having a great deal of difficulty finding recipes for this scenario. I would like to avoid as many moving parts as possible, so not interested in using things like AD FS, WIF, etc... if at all possible.

Does anyone have a good resource for setting up this type of IdP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this 3rd party expect the token?

Via a web-service (WS-Trust), WS-Federation, SAML?

SP has an STS but it doesn't support SAML.

It sounds like the easiest way is to use ADFS for the heavy lifting.

Comment: Right - so other than ADFS and a SAML WIF CTP (ages old), there is no Microsoft SAML support. So either ADFS or some commercial .NET SAML library.

Comment: I actually got a pretty decent SAML Token using the method outlined here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56640/Performing-a-SAML-Post-with-C, though it took quite a lot of tweaking, and I had to figure out my own encryption of the Assertion. Thanks for responses, nz, I've actually read quite a lot of posts on SAML here that you supplied a great deal of high quality advice on. Cheers, m8!